# No such file or directory vertica-8.0.0-0.x86_64.RHEL6.rpm vertica on vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vertica, vagrant-provision

I used vagrant to deploy a virtual machine(The virtual machines runs Linux red hat OS) on virtualbox. I am trying to run vertica on the VM however every time I `vagrant up` provision fails and I get this error:

```
No such file or directory vertica-8.0.0-0.x86_64.RHEL6.rpm

The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I downloaded vertica-8.0.0-0.x86_64.RHEL6.rpm from vertica portal and it is in the same directory as my Vagrantfile

I tried a bunch of other solutions online but nothing seems to work still

Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Comment: can you paste your provisionning script ?

Comment: It is fixed now, so the problem was that my script was expecting unix line-endings but it was getting windows line endings. It got fixed by running a dos2unix on the script.